# Use specific cell colour in conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I've created a planning calendar for a client where a graphical calendar is displayed based on a reference table of room, activity, start time & end times.

It's been coded so that the rooms and times aren't specific to this client so we can offer it to someone else, and it's also locked-down to prevent them editing/breaking it.

The only thing that stops it being workable for any client is the conditional formatting; i.e. if there's a meeting, shade the cell blue, if it's a conference, purple with white text etc.

I can get this to work by hard-coding the conditional formatting rule colours, but different clients will have different activities and different colours (and they're very fussy about colours!).

So, what I've done is added a separate tab "Formatting" which pulls a distinct list of all activities, and a cell next to it where they can choose their cell & font colours.

Where I'm stumped is, getting the conditional formatting rule to say: if text contains "cell A2", then use the formatting of "cell B2", repeating down to row 20.
I've got the first bit working:

```
 Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="=Formatting!$A$2", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
```

But it's the:

```
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 4.99893185216834E-02
End With
```

and

```
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 10092543
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
```

parts which I can't figure out how to populate using the font and interior colour of the adjacent cell (B2)

Any suggestions?

Comment: How about just referencing the other cell's properties, e.g. `.Interior.Color =range("b2").interior.color` ?

Comment: Dude... So simple, thanks! I was trying to extract RGB colours and use those!